# Click on a link and then change ip with python mechanize

Tags: python, click, ip, mechanize

Is there the possibility to write a script in python that looks for a target link on a website, then clicks on it, and finally changes the ip-address  and so on in a loop?

Some examples?

I tried to understand mechanize but there's no documentation in the internet, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large set of proxies in a collection you can connect through I don't see why you wouldn't be able to do this.

```
proxies = {"proxy_one", "proxy_two", "proxy_three"}
// Not a python guy, this syntax could be completely wrong and I'm sorry, please feel free to edit this

for proxy in proxies:
  req = mechanize.Request("http://www.google.com")
  req.set_proxy(element,"http")
  mechanize.urlopen(req)
```